# How can I insert a link inside a <p> and keep it inline with spans and other parts of text

Tags: html, css, anchor, block, inline

My code is this

```
<style type="text/css">



.post-infos {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 174px;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.9);
    padding: 5px 12px 12px 12px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.post-infos .main {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #222;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.post-infos .main p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.post-infos .main a {
    color: #222;
}

.post-infos .main a:hover {
    color: #26abd3;
}

.post-infos .main .title {
    margin-right: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}



</style>








<div class="post-infos">
<div class="main">

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<span class="title">
Title of the Movie
</span>
</a>

(2015)

</div>
</div>
```

and it displays like this

[How it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM1Fw.png)

because the title is into an anchor and the anchor has got a rectangular shape, so the year will always go down

but I'd like to have it like this:

[How it should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCneK.jpg)

As you can see in the second movie the year goes down even if it fits the row, but I'd like to have it on the same row of the title when it fits, just like a part of a text in a `<p>`. It's actually really simple: I'd like to have it displayed like a simple `<p>`, but with a part inside a link, and the other part doesn't have to go down to the next row. I'd like to have it on the right of the title if it's enough small to stay on that row, and to go down only if it doesn't fit the row, like it does in a `<p>`.

Thanks in advance for any help

Can you just take a look at it? `http://echidnavideos.altervista.org`

When the whole thing is just one row, it's okay, the year is displayed next to the title. When the year doesn't fit the last row, it's okay, it goes below. But when the title occupies more than one row and the year should be next to it, it goes below.

Comment: please provide some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the multi-line problem with the code you gave: https://jsfiddle.net/c0aqc6hp/

Comment: Can you just take a look at it? http://echidnavideos.altervista.org/

When the whole thing is just one row, it's okay, the year is displayed next to the title. When the year doesn't fit the last row, it's okay, it goes below. But when the title occupies more than one row and the year should be next to it, it goes below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this:

```
 .post-infos .main a {
     color: #222;
     display: block; /* that's the change */
 }
```

The year will be displayed ever in the bottom of the title without changing your html structure. This is because `a` tag is an inline tag, and the simple text will positioned by an stack. With display block your `a` tag will occupy all horizontal space.

Tell me if something is wrong

Comment: I actually didn't want to make the `a` occupy the whole horizontal space, but the opposite. I wanted the year to be on the right of the title when it could be. But now it's just fine and in fact i realize that the normal structure of a `a` is this, to be inline so... anyway thanks for the answer, it just solved itself out, maybe there was some closure tag out of place

Comment: Oh, I understand wrong, the opposite as you said, sorry.